# How to keep number with n digits by keeping leftside '0'?

Tags: javascript, string, numbers

I do a for loop and would like to get it well aligned.

```
for(var i=7;i<14; i++){ console.log( i ) }
```

I get

```
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
```

I want

```
07
08
09
10
11
12
13
```

**Is there a built in way to do that ?**
Without cascading testing such `i.length=1?'0'+i:i;`)

---

For now I use `.toPrecision(2)` :

```
5.00
6.00
7.00
8.00
9.00
10.0
11.0
12.0
13.0
14.0
```

but it is suboptimal as iterations are integers and cannot have ".xx" .

Comment: `function prepad( num ) { return num < 10 ? '0' + num : num.toString(); }` No builtin afaik.

Comment: @Shilly `String#padStart`.

Comment: @Xufox Thanks! But not compatible with IE < edge alas. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concatenate `"00"` and your number, and use [`String.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) with a negative number.

```js
for (var i = 7; i < 14; i++) {
  console.log(("00" + i).slice(-2));
}
```

Sometime in the future you can use [`String.padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) for such things:

```js
for (var i = 7; i < 14; i++) {
  console.log(i.toString().padStart(2, "0"));
}
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it doesn't work with numbers above 100

Comment: `('00'+i).slice(-2)` seems elegant !

Answer (score 5):

You could use [Number#toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) with the right options.

```js
var i;
for (i = 7; i < 14; i++) {
    console.log(i.toLocaleString(undefined, { minimumIntegerDigits: 2 }))
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Didn't know this was possible :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [String.prototype.padStart()](https://developer.mozilla.org/cs/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart#Examples) and if it's not natively available, you could add its polyfill, see follow:

```js
if (!String.prototype.padStart) {
    String.prototype.padStart = function padStart(targetLength,padString) {
        targetLength = targetLength>>0; //floor if number or convert non-number to 0;
        padString = String(padString || ' ');
        if (this.length > targetLength) {
            return String(this);
        }
        else {
            targetLength = targetLength-this.length;
            if (targetLength > padString.length) {
                padString += padString.repeat(targetLength/padString.length); //append to original to ensure we are longer than needed
            }
            return padString.slice(0,targetLength) + String(this);
        }
    };
}

for (var i = 7; i < 14; i++) {
  console.log(new String(i).padStart(2, '0'));
}
```

I hope it helps you, bye.

Comment: Thanks. :)
I my case I will go for Salman's answer.

Answer (score 1):

```js
for(var i = 7; i < 14; i++){
    console.log(prependZero(i));
}

function prependZero(number) {
    if (number < 10 && number >= 0) {
        number = '0' + number;
    }
    
    return number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check this code. this is built in function

```
<script>
    for (var i = 7; i < 14; i++) {
        console.log(i.toString().padStart(2, "0"));
    }
   </script>
```

output :

```
07  
08  
09  
10  
11  
12  
13
```

you can use also slice

```
 for (var i = 7; i < 14; i++) {
            console.log(("00" + i).slice(-2));
        }
```

if you use slice and number > 100

```
for (var i = 99; i < 104; i++) {
        console.log(("00" + i).slice(-3));
    }
```

Comment: This is correct but basically put a test in.

Comment: not clear which you tell

Comment: i am missing last question section, so check now